# How can "/dev/binde" file be mmaped by service_manager and server in android framework?

Tags: android, linux

I'm now analyzing the android framwork internal and 
I found the mmap() was called twice by each module in android framework as referring the same file "dev/binder".

1) Could someone explain how it works to mmap() twice refreing same file?

2) Could someone explain how memory map by mmap() is organized in this case?

1. -----------------------------------------------------------------------

BINDER_VM_SIZE : 1M-8K

mDriverFD : refering "dev/binder"

ProcessState::ProcessState()
{

mmap(0, BINDER_VM_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_PROVATE|MAP_NORESERVE, mDriverFD, 0);

}

2. -----------------------------------------------------------------------

in service_manager.c, binder_open() is being called as below.

mapsize : 128K

struct binder_state *binder_open(unsiged mapsize)
{

bs->fd = open("dev/binder", O_RDWR);

mmap(NULL, mapsize, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, bs->fd, 0);

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Plz format code in the question.

Comment: /dev/binder is not really a "file" but rather a file-like interface (in keeping with the unix "everything is a file") to Android's custom kernel IPC mechanism called binder.  Effectively binder is how 3rd party apps and services call and pass data to and from the back ends of system components which run in other system-owned processes.  You'll probably want to read up on that, and possibly examine the source of binder itself within an Android-ized Linux kernel tree.

Comment: Yes, I know the role of binder in android system. but I want to know how mmap() twice referring same device file, "/dev/binder" while requesting different address spaces like 128K and 1M-8K. I guess it is working with mmap() option "MT_PRIVATE". but I'm not sure how the area generated by mmap() is managed.

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer I transfer it to english
https://blog.csdn.net/mafei852213034/article/details/117783841

The work of binder_open() is also relatively simple; it is divided into the following steps;

1. Open by system call open(); /dev/binder; obtain a handle information; in the Binder driver, the corresponding function binder_open()
2. Obtain the version information of the binder through ioctl; compare whether the version of the binder protocol is the same; if it is different, it will jump out; in the binder driver, the corresponding function binder_ioctl()
3. Map the 128K memory space through mmap memory; that is map the 128K bytes of the binder driver file to the memory space; this 128K memory space is used by the servicemanager. The corresponding function in the Binder driver is binder_mmap().
   Other binder service processes will map the memory space of BINDER_VM_SIZE ((1 * 1024 * 1024) - sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) * 2);

sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) = 4096 is 1 page size.

service_manager.c

```
bs = binder_open(128*1024);
binder_become_context_manager(bs);
```

//in user space
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r60/cmds/servicemanager/binder.c

```
int binder_become_context_manager(struct binder_state *bs)
{
    return ioctl(bs->fd, BINDER_SET_CONTEXT_MGR, 0);
}
```

128K for BINDER_SET_CONTEXT_MGR

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//constructure init mmap
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/jb-dev/libs/binder/ProcessState.cpp

```
#define BINDER_VM_SIZE ((1*1024*1024) - (4096 *2))

ProcessState::ProcessState()
{
    ....
    mVMStart = mmap(0, BINDER_VM_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_NORESERVE, mDriverFD, 0);
}
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/jb-dev/libs/binder/IPCThreadState.cpp

```
#if defined(HAVE_ANDROID_OS)
        if (ioctl(mProcess->mDriverFD, BINDER_WRITE_READ, &bwr) >= 0)
            err = NO_ERROR;
        else
            err = -errno;
#else
        err = INVALID_OPERATION;
#endif
```

IPCThreadState.h

```
const   sp<ProcessState>    mProcess;
```

1M-8K for data BINDER_WRITE_READ with onTransact

//trace into linux driver
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.13.19/source/drivers/android/binder.c#L4721

```
static long binder_ioctl(struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    ....
    case BINDER_WRITE_READ:
        ret = binder_ioctl_write_read(filp, cmd, arg, thread);
        if (ret)
            goto err;
        break;

    case BINDER_SET_CONTEXT_MGR:
        ret = binder_ioctl_set_ctx_mgr(filp, NULL);
        if (ret)
            goto err;
        break;
}
```